# DCOUNT function doesn't return the correct result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, dcount

I tried hard but couldn't found out why the formula in cell `S10` below returns value `0` instead of `1`, could you explain?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@gtwebb has a simple solution but just adding an `A` is also simple:

```
=DCOUNTA(O5:Q19,"COLOR",R1:T2)
```

and will not produce the same result as counting `NO` if C2 values in the relevant range are matched against one or more blanks for COLOR.

[DCOUNTA](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/DCOUNTA-function-00232a6d-5a66-4a01-a25b-c1653fda1244)

Answer (score 1):

From the help menu of dcount

> Counts the cells that contain **numbers** in a field (column) of records in a list or database that match conditions that you specify.

The problem is you don't have any numbers in the colour column.  Try counting you "NO" column.